# Формат ячейки в Excel с помощью модуля openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

Может кто знает как с помощью модуля openpyxl, передать  число не в формате общий а именно формате числовой. Третья колонка передается в формате общий.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    def exportFile(self, nameFileExport, dataList, range, columnsExport):
        wb = workbook.Workbook()
        wb.guess_types = True
        ws = wb.active
        ws.append(columnsExport)
        range_ = range + str(len(dataList) + 1)  
        for row in dataList:
            ws.append(row)
        tab = Table(displayName='Table1', ref=range_)
        ws.add_table(tab)
        wb.save(nameFileExport)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Openpyxl number format](http://www.whiteboardcoder.com/2020/02/openpyxl-number-format.html), [number_format](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.styles.styleable.html?highlight=number_format#openpyxl.styles.styleable.StyleableObject.number_format)

```
import openpyxl.styles.numbers
cell.number_format = openpyxl.styles.numbers.BUILTIN_FORMATS[2]
```

Lib\site-packages\openpyxl\styles\numbers.py:

```
BUILTIN_FORMATS = {
    0: 'General',
    1: '0',
    2: '0.00',
    3: '#,##0',
    4: '#,##0.00',
    5: '"$"#,##0_);("$"#,##0)',
    6: '"$"#,##0_);[Red]("$"#,##0)',
    7: '"$"#,##0.00_);("$"#,##0.00)',
    8: '"$"#,##0.00_);[Red]("$"#,##0.00)',
    9: '0%',
    10: '0.00%',
    11: '0.00E+00',
    12: '# ?/?',
    13: '# ??/??',
    14: 'mm-dd-yy',
    15: 'd-mmm-yy',
    16: 'd-mmm',
    17: 'mmm-yy',
    18: 'h:mm AM/PM',
    19: 'h:mm:ss AM/PM',
    20: 'h:mm',
    21: 'h:mm:ss',
    22: 'm/d/yy h:mm',

    37: '#,##0_);(#,##0)',
    38: '#,##0_);[Red](#,##0)',
    39: '#,##0.00_);(#,##0.00)',
    40: '#,##0.00_);[Red](#,##0.00)',

    41: r'_(* #,##0_);_(* \(#,##0\);_(* "-"_);_(@_)',
    42: r'_("$"* #,##0_);_("$"* \(#,##0\);_("$"* "-"_);_(@_)',
    43: r'_(* #,##0.00_);_(* \(#,##0.00\);_(* "-"??_);_(@_)',

    44: r'_("$"* #,##0.00_)_("$"* \(#,##0.00\)_("$"* "-"??_)_(@_)',
    45: 'mm:ss',
    46: '[h]:mm:ss',
    47: 'mmss.0',
    48: '##0.0E+0',
    49: '@', }
```